# Not downloading 64Bit version of IE Driver using WebDriverManager

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver, webdrivermanager-java

64bit version of IE Driver is not downloading using WebDriverManager.

As per description provided at https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager, it states

> By default, WebDriverManager would try to use the proper binary for
>   the platform running the test case (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit).

But by default it is downloading 32bit on 64bit system.

If I force webdrivermanager to download 64bit using below code,

```
System.setProperty("wdm.targetPath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\driver");
        WebDriverManager.iedriver().architecture(Architecture.X64).arch64().setup();
```

receiving error,

> io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException:
>   io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: IEDriverServer
>   (latest version) for WIN64 not found in
>   https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/

But 64bit IEDriver is available at the above url, only difference is in naming conversion of .zip file, 32bit contains Win32, whereas 64bit contains x64

```
<Contents>
<Key>3.12/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.12.0.zip</Key>
<Generation>1525799912941276</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>2018-05-08T17:18:32.903Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"da29d5967726b1b41e7df9d823985277"</ETag>
<Size>1063545</Size>
</Contents>
<Contents>
<Key>3.12/IEDriverServer_x64_3.12.0.zip</Key>
<Generation>1525799913484150</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>2018-05-08T17:18:33.446Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"c058b42ed67b53784403035041735011"</ETag>
<Size>1175137</Size>
</Contents>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, solved in version 2.2.3, recently released.